# Parsing JSON data into SELECT prints UNDEFINED

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

My JSON being sent from the server is like this:

```
data[
{"userFullName":"Tim, Bill","id":"LOt3","organisation":"FAP","loginSystem":"A","userId":0},{"userFullName":"Bruce, David","id":"LNA","organisation":"ES","loginSystem":"A","userId":0}
]
```

In the success of my AJAX call,I am handling the data as follows :

```
 success: function (data) {
 javascript: console.log('data' + data);
 $.each(data, function(key, value) {
 javascript: console.log('id' + value.id);
 $('#selectStaff').append('<option value="' + value.id+ '">' + value.userFullName + '</option>');
 });
 }
```

selectStaff is the ID of the SELECT control...

The SELECT control is drawing with 'undefined' populated in the drop down.

`The console.log('data' + data)` prints the following line:

```
data[{"userFullName":"Tim, Bill","id":"LOt3","organisation":"FAP","loginSystem":"A","userId":0},{"userFullName":"Bruce, David","id":"LNA","organisation":"ES","loginSystem":"A","userId":0}]
```

However, the line javascript: `console.log('id' + value.id)` prints out 'UNDEFINED'

Would someone please describe the correct syntax to me?

Comment: possibly typo for `val.ident` where it should have been `val.id` http://jsfiddle.net/YY8jY/

Comment: The error doesn't seem to be related to the code. I don't see you call `obj.val` anywhere. Where exactly do you see `undefined`?

Comment: @shyam I made the fix but the issue still appears to be there. Thanks for the fiddle

Comment: @John Can you replicate your issue in the fiddle?

Comment: @shyam I tried. It is working in the fiddle but I get the SELECT drawing with values 'Undefined' Not sure what I am missing..

Comment: @John then it looks like the problem is somewhere else. you need to post a larger sample of code which exhibits the problem

Comment: @shyam I have extended the code snippet and also added a log statement in the success function. The data appears to be coming fine however when I attempt to extract the JSON pieces, it fails.

Answer (score 1):

Error in your code `val.id`

Working Fine

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/45wC8/1/)

Script

```
    var user=[{"userFullName":"be, apple","id":"xdsd3","organisation":"FL ","userId":0},{"userFullName":"Mack, David","id":"lol323","organisation":"ES","userId":0}]

$.each(user, function(key, value) {
   console.log('id' + value.id);
                            $('#selectStaff').append('<option value="' + value.id + '">' + value.userFullName + '</option>');
                        });
```

Comment: Is there any advantage to using this over just a normal for-loop? Especially since his server is returning an array, like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/6FPLM/2/)? I know OP didn't mention anything about performance, but for loop would be better, at least according to [Sam Deering](http://www.jquery4u.com/jquery-functions/speed-question-jquery-each-vs-loop/).

Comment: Sorry. It is still giving me an undefined when the SELECT draws.

Comment: in fiddle no error we get john.which browser and jquery you use?

Comment: @SridharR I am using Chrome and IE. I have tried to replicate the issue in the fiddle but couldn't.

Comment: @SridharR I have extended the code snippet with log statements. Could you please take another look. Thanks.